# Azure tables, Retrieve data

Tags: vb.net, azure, azure-table-storage

I was trying to pull certain data from the retrieveResult below. How would I do that:

```
Dim accountname As String = My.Settings.Repository
        Dim accountkey As String = My.Settings.StorageKey
        Dim creds As StorageCredentials = New StorageCredentials(accountname, accountkey)
        Dim account As CloudStorageAccount = New CloudStorageAccount(creds, useHttps:=True)
        Dim client As CloudTableClient = account.CreateCloudTableClient()
        Dim table As CloudTable = client.GetTableReference(My.Settings.Table)

        Dim retrieveOperation As TableOperation
        Dim retrievedResult As TableResult
        retrieveOperation = TableOperation.Retrieve(Of NameRecord)(var_SystemID, var_TagName) 
        retrievedResult = table.Execute(retrieveOperation)
```

So RetrievedResult returns basically whole record from the table.

My question is how I access Record number property from Retrieved result?
[image]

Thank you

Comment: Did you try `retrievedResult.Result.Record`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@Gaurav Mantri is correct, it's as simple as using this line of code  `retrievedResult.Result.Record`.

Please let me know if you still have the issue.

Comment: I was expecting for VS to give me suggestions but instead I had: .Result. Equals/GetHashCode/GetType/ToString available only.... Thank you . It worked